# error: invalid operands of types 'bool' and 'int' to binary 'operator<=> - (GCC 10 - std=gnu++20)

Tags: c++, freebsd, c++20, gcc10

i have some c++ project after a release of support c++20, i want to upgrade my makefile std support 17 to 20 after that point my compiler (gcc10.2) give me a error like this ;

[Error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/NJvEw.png)

```
In file included from /usr/local/lib/gcc10/include/c++/bits/node_handle.h:39,
                 from /usr/local/lib/gcc10/include/c++/bits/stl_tree.h:72,
                 from /usr/local/lib/gcc10/include/c++/map:60,
                 from AsyncSQL.h:10,
                 from AsyncSQL.cpp:4:
/usr/local/lib/gcc10/include/c++/optional: In function 'constexpr std::strong_ordering std::operator<=>(const std::optional<_Tp>&, std::nullopt_t)':
/usr/local/lib/gcc10/include/c++/optional:1052:24: error: invalid operands of types 'bool' and 'int' to binary 'operator<=>'
 1052 |     { return bool(__x) <=> false; }
      |              ~~~~~~~~~ ^~~
      |              |
      |              bool
gmake[2]: *** [Makefile:23: AsyncSQL.o] Error 1
```

This is my AsyncSQL.cpp ;

```
#include <sys/time.h>
#include <cstdlib>
#include <cstring>
#include "AsyncSQL.h"
#define MUTEX_LOCK(mtx)   pthread_mutex_lock(mtx)
#define MUTEX_UNLOCK(mtx) pthread_mutex_unlock(mtx)

CAsyncSQL::CAsyncSQL(): m_stHost (""), m_stUser (""), m_stPassword (""), m_stDB (""), m_stLocale (""), m_iMsgCount (0), m_iPort (0), m_bEnd (false), m_hThread (0), m_mtxQuery (NULL), m_mtxResult (NULL), m_iQueryFinished (0), m_ulThreadID (0), m_bConnected (false), m_iCopiedQuery (0)
{
    memset (&m_hDB, 0, sizeof (m_hDB));

    m_aiPipe[0] = 0;
    m_aiPipe[1] = 0;
}

CAsyncSQL::~CAsyncSQL()
{
    Quit();
    Destroy();
}

void CAsyncSQL::Destroy()
{
    if (m_hDB.host)
    {
        sys_log (0, "AsyncSQL: closing mysql connection.");
        mysql_close (&m_hDB);
        m_hDB.host = NULL;
    }

    if (m_mtxQuery)
    {
        pthread_mutex_destroy (m_mtxQuery);
        delete m_mtxQuery;
        m_mtxQuery = NULL;
    }

    if (m_mtxResult)
    {
        pthread_mutex_destroy (m_mtxResult);
        delete m_mtxResult;
        m_mtxQuery = NULL;
    }
}

void* AsyncSQLThread (void* arg)
{
    CAsyncSQL* pSQL = ((CAsyncSQL*) arg);

    if (!pSQL->Connect())
    {
        return NULL;
    }

    pSQL->ChildLoop();
    return NULL;
}

bool CAsyncSQL::QueryLocaleSet()
{
    if (0 == m_stLocale.length())
    {
        sys_err ("m_stLocale == 0");
        return true;
    }

    if (mysql_set_character_set (&m_hDB, m_stLocale.c_str()))
    {
        sys_err ("cannot set locale %s by 'mysql_set_character_set', errno %u %s", m_stLocale.c_str(), mysql_errno (&m_hDB) , mysql_error (&m_hDB));
        return false;
    }

    sys_log (0, "\t--mysql_set_character_set(%s)", m_stLocale.c_str());

    return true;
}

bool CAsyncSQL::Connect()
{
    if (0 == mysql_init (&m_hDB))
    {
        fprintf (stderr, "mysql_init failed\n");
        return false;
    }

    if (!m_stLocale.empty())
    {
        if (mysql_options (&m_hDB, MYSQL_SET_CHARSET_NAME, m_stLocale.c_str()) != 0)
        {
            fprintf (stderr, "mysql_option failed : MYSQL_SET_CHARSET_NAME %s ", mysql_error(&m_hDB));
        }
    }

    if (!mysql_real_connect (&m_hDB, m_stHost.c_str(), m_stUser.c_str(), m_stPassword.c_str(), m_stDB.c_str(), m_iPort, NULL, CLIENT_MULTI_STATEMENTS))
    {
        fprintf (stderr, "mysql_real_connect: %s\n", mysql_error(&m_hDB));
        return false;
    }

    my_bool reconnect = true;

    if (0 != mysql_options (&m_hDB, MYSQL_OPT_RECONNECT, &reconnect))
    {
        fprintf (stderr, "mysql_option: %s\n", mysql_error(&m_hDB));
    }



    m_ulThreadID = mysql_thread_id (&m_hDB);

    m_bConnected = true;
    return true;
}

bool CAsyncSQL::Setup (CAsyncSQL* sql, bool bNoThread)
{
    return Setup (sql->m_stHost.c_str(), sql->m_stUser.c_str(), sql->m_stPassword.c_str(), sql->m_stDB.c_str(), sql->m_stLocale.c_str(), bNoThread, sql->m_iPort);
}

bool CAsyncSQL::Setup (const char* c_pszHost, const char* c_pszUser, const char* c_pszPassword, const char* c_pszDB, const char* c_pszLocale, bool bNoThread, int iPort)
{
    m_stHost = c_pszHost;
    m_stUser = c_pszUser;
    m_stPassword = c_pszPassword;
    m_stDB  = c_pszDB;
    m_iPort = iPort;

    if (c_pszLocale)
    {
        m_stLocale = c_pszLocale;
        sys_log (0, "AsyncSQL: locale %s", m_stLocale.c_str());
    }

    if (!bNoThread)
    {
        m_mtxQuery  = new pthread_mutex_t;
        m_mtxResult = new pthread_mutex_t;

        if (0 != pthread_mutex_init (m_mtxQuery, NULL))
        {
            perror ("pthread_mutex_init");
            exit (0);
        }

        if (0 != pthread_mutex_init (m_mtxResult, NULL))
        {
            perror ("pthread_mutex_init");
            exit (0);
        }

        pthread_create (&m_hThread, NULL, AsyncSQLThread, this);

        return true;
    }
    else
    {
        return Connect();
    }
}

void CAsyncSQL::Quit()
{
    m_bEnd = true;
    m_sem.Release();

    if (m_hThread)
    {
        pthread_join (m_hThread, NULL);
        m_hThread = NULL;
    }
}

SQLMsg* CAsyncSQL::DirectQuery (const char* c_pszQuery)
{
    if (m_ulThreadID != mysql_thread_id (&m_hDB))
    {
        sys_log (0, "MySQL connection was reconnected. querying locale set");
        while (!QueryLocaleSet());
        m_ulThreadID = mysql_thread_id (&m_hDB);
    }

    SQLMsg* p = new SQLMsg;

    p->m_pkSQL = &m_hDB;
    p->iID = ++m_iMsgCount;
    p->stQuery = c_pszQuery;

    if (mysql_real_query (&m_hDB, p->stQuery.c_str(), p->stQuery.length()))
    {
        char buf[1024];

        snprintf (buf, sizeof(buf), "AsyncSQL::DirectQuery : mysql_query error: %s\nquery: %s", mysql_error (&m_hDB), p->stQuery.c_str());

        sys_err (buf);
        p->uiSQLErrno = mysql_errno (&m_hDB);
    }

    p->Store();
    return p;
}

void CAsyncSQL::AsyncQuery (const char* c_pszQuery)
{
    auto p = new SQLMsg;

    p->m_pkSQL = &m_hDB;
    p->iID = ++m_iMsgCount;
    p->stQuery = c_pszQuery;

    PushQuery (p);
}

void CAsyncSQL::ReturnQuery (const char* c_pszQuery, void* pvUserData)
{
    auto p = new SQLMsg;

    p->m_pkSQL = &m_hDB;
    p->iID = ++m_iMsgCount;
    p->stQuery = c_pszQuery;
    p->bReturn = true;
    p->pvUserData = pvUserData;

    PushQuery (p);
}

void CAsyncSQL::PushResult (SQLMsg* p)
{
    MUTEX_LOCK (m_mtxResult);

    m_queue_result.push (p);

    MUTEX_UNLOCK (m_mtxResult);
}

bool CAsyncSQL::PopResult(SQLMsg** pp)
{
    MUTEX_LOCK (m_mtxResult);

    if (m_queue_result.empty())
    {
        MUTEX_UNLOCK (m_mtxResult);
        return false;
    }

    *pp = m_queue_result.front();
    m_queue_result.pop();
    MUTEX_UNLOCK (m_mtxResult);
    return true;
}

void CAsyncSQL::PushQuery (SQLMsg* p)
{
    MUTEX_LOCK (m_mtxQuery);

    m_queue_query.push (p);
    m_sem.Release();

    MUTEX_UNLOCK (m_mtxQuery);
}

bool CAsyncSQL::PeekQuery (SQLMsg** pp)
{
    MUTEX_LOCK (m_mtxQuery);

    if (m_queue_query.empty())
    {
        MUTEX_UNLOCK (m_mtxQuery);
        return false;
    }

    *pp = m_queue_query.front();
    MUTEX_UNLOCK (m_mtxQuery);
    return true;
}

bool CAsyncSQL::PopQuery (int iID)
{
    MUTEX_LOCK (m_mtxQuery);

    if (m_queue_query.empty())
    {
        MUTEX_UNLOCK (m_mtxQuery);
        return false;
    }

    m_queue_query.pop();
    MUTEX_UNLOCK (m_mtxQuery);
    return true;
}

bool CAsyncSQL::PeekQueryFromCopyQueue (SQLMsg** pp)
{
    if (m_queue_query_copy.empty())
    {
        return false;
    }

    *pp = m_queue_query_copy.front();
    return true;
}

int CAsyncSQL::CopyQuery()
{
    MUTEX_LOCK (m_mtxQuery);

    if (m_queue_query.empty())
    {
        MUTEX_UNLOCK (m_mtxQuery);
        return -1;
    }

    while (!m_queue_query.empty())
    {
        SQLMsg* p = m_queue_query.front();
        m_queue_query_copy.push (p);
        m_queue_query.pop();
    }
    int count = m_queue_query_copy.size();

    MUTEX_UNLOCK (m_mtxQuery);
    return count;
}

bool CAsyncSQL::PopQueryFromCopyQueue()
{
    if (m_queue_query_copy.empty())
    {
        return false;
    }

    m_queue_query_copy.pop();
    return true;
}

int CAsyncSQL::GetCopiedQueryCount()
{
    return m_iCopiedQuery;
}

void CAsyncSQL::ResetCopiedQueryCount()
{
    m_iCopiedQuery = 0;
}

void CAsyncSQL::AddCopiedQueryCount (int iCopiedQuery)
{
    m_iCopiedQuery += iCopiedQuery;
}

DWORD CAsyncSQL::CountQuery()
{
    return m_queue_query.size();
}

DWORD CAsyncSQL::CountResult()
{
    return m_queue_result.size();
}

void __timediff (struct timeval* a, struct timeval* b, struct timeval* rslt)
{
    if (a->tv_sec < b->tv_sec)
    {
        rslt->tv_sec = rslt->tv_usec = 0;
    }
    else if (a->tv_sec == b->tv_sec)
    {
        if (a->tv_usec < b->tv_usec)
        {
            rslt->tv_sec = rslt->tv_usec = 0;
        }
        else
        {
            rslt->tv_sec = 0;
            rslt->tv_usec = a->tv_usec - b->tv_usec;
        }
    }
    else
    {
        rslt->tv_sec = a->tv_sec - b->tv_sec;

        if (a->tv_usec < b->tv_usec)
        {
            rslt->tv_usec = a->tv_usec + 1000000 - b->tv_usec;
            rslt->tv_sec--;
        }
        else
        {
            rslt->tv_usec = a->tv_usec - b->tv_usec;
        }
    }
}

class cProfiler
{
public:
    cProfiler()
    {
        m_nInterval = 0 ;

        memset (&prev, 0, sizeof (prev));
        memset (&now,  0, sizeof (now));
        memset (&interval, 0, sizeof (interval));

        Start();
    }

    cProfiler (int nInterval = 100000)
    {
        m_nInterval = nInterval;

        memset (&prev, 0, sizeof (prev));
        memset (&now,  0, sizeof (now));
        memset (&interval, 0, sizeof (interval));

        Start();
    }

    void Start()
    {
        gettimeofday (&prev , (struct timezone*) 0);
    }

    void Stop()
    {
        gettimeofday (&now, (struct timezone*) 0); 
        __timediff (&now, &prev, &interval);
    }

    bool IsOk()
    {
        if (interval.tv_sec > (m_nInterval / 1000000))
        {
            return false;
        }

        if (interval.tv_usec > m_nInterval)
        {
            return false;
        }

        return true;
    }

    struct timeval* GetResult()
    {
        return &interval;
    }
    long GetResultSec()
    {
        return interval.tv_sec;
    }
    long GetResultUSec()
    {
        return interval.tv_usec;
    }

private:
    int m_nInterval;
    struct timeval prev;
    struct timeval now;
    struct timeval interval;
};

void CAsyncSQL::ChildLoop()
{
    cProfiler profiler(500000);

    while (!m_bEnd)
    {
        m_sem.Wait();

        int count = CopyQuery();

        if (count <= 0)
        {
            continue;
        }

        AddCopiedQueryCount (count);

        SQLMsg* p;

        while (count--)
        {
            profiler.Start();

            if (!PeekQueryFromCopyQueue (&p))
            {
                continue;
            }

            if (m_ulThreadID != mysql_thread_id (&m_hDB))
            {
                sys_log (0, "MySQL connection was reconnected. querying locale set");
                while (!QueryLocaleSet());
                m_ulThreadID = mysql_thread_id (&m_hDB);
            }

            if (mysql_real_query (&m_hDB, p->stQuery.c_str(), p->stQuery.length()))
            {
                p->uiSQLErrno = mysql_errno (&m_hDB);

                sys_err ("AsyncSQL: query failed: %s (query: %s errno: %d)", mysql_error (&m_hDB), p->stQuery.c_str(), p->uiSQLErrno);

                switch (p->uiSQLErrno)
                {
                    case CR_SOCKET_CREATE_ERROR:
                    case CR_CONNECTION_ERROR:
                    case CR_IPSOCK_ERROR:
                    case CR_UNKNOWN_HOST:
                    case CR_SERVER_GONE_ERROR:
                    case CR_CONN_HOST_ERROR:
                    case ER_NOT_KEYFILE:
                    case ER_CRASHED_ON_USAGE:
                    case ER_CANT_OPEN_FILE:
                    case ER_HOST_NOT_PRIVILEGED:
                    case ER_HOST_IS_BLOCKED:
                    case ER_PASSWORD_NOT_ALLOWED:
                    case ER_PASSWORD_NO_MATCH:
                    case ER_CANT_CREATE_THREAD:
                    case ER_INVALID_USE_OF_NULL:
                        m_sem.Release();
                        sys_err ("AsyncSQL: retrying");
                        continue;
                }
            }

            profiler.Stop();

            if (!profiler.IsOk())
            {
                sys_log (0, "[QUERY : LONG INTERVAL(OverSec %ld.%ld)] : %s", profiler.GetResultSec(), profiler.GetResultUSec(), p->stQuery.c_str());
            }

            PopQueryFromCopyQueue();

            if (p->bReturn)
            {
                p->Store();
                PushResult (p);
            }
            else
            {
                delete p;
            }

            ++m_iQueryFinished;
        }
    }

    SQLMsg* p;

    while (PeekQuery (&p))
    {
        if (m_ulThreadID != mysql_thread_id (&m_hDB))
        {
            sys_log (0, "MySQL connection was reconnected. querying locale set");
            while (!QueryLocaleSet());
            m_ulThreadID = mysql_thread_id (&m_hDB);
        }

        if (mysql_real_query (&m_hDB, p->stQuery.c_str(), p->stQuery.length()))
        {
            p->uiSQLErrno = mysql_errno (&m_hDB);

            sys_err ("AsyncSQL::ChildLoop : mysql_query error: %s:\nquery: %s", mysql_error (&m_hDB), p->stQuery.c_str());

            switch (p->uiSQLErrno)
            {
                case CR_SOCKET_CREATE_ERROR:
                case CR_CONNECTION_ERROR:
                case CR_IPSOCK_ERROR:
                case CR_UNKNOWN_HOST:
                case CR_SERVER_GONE_ERROR:
                case CR_CONN_HOST_ERROR:
                case ER_NOT_KEYFILE:
                case ER_CRASHED_ON_USAGE:
                case ER_CANT_OPEN_FILE:
                case ER_HOST_NOT_PRIVILEGED:
                case ER_HOST_IS_BLOCKED:
                case ER_PASSWORD_NOT_ALLOWED:
                case ER_PASSWORD_NO_MATCH:
                case ER_CANT_CREATE_THREAD:
                case ER_INVALID_USE_OF_NULL:
                    continue;
            }
        }

        sys_log (0, "QUERY_FLUSH: %s", p->stQuery.c_str());

        PopQuery (p->iID);

        if (p->bReturn)
        {
            p->Store();
            PushResult (p);
        }
        else
        {
            delete p;
        }

        ++m_iQueryFinished;
    }
}

int CAsyncSQL::CountQueryFinished()
{
    return m_iQueryFinished;
}

void CAsyncSQL::ResetQueryFinished()
{
    m_iQueryFinished = 0;
}

MYSQL* CAsyncSQL::GetSQLHandle()
{
    return &m_hDB;
}

size_t CAsyncSQL::EscapeString (char* dst, size_t dstSize, const char* src, size_t srcSize)
{
    if (0 == srcSize)
    {
        memset (dst, 0, dstSize);
        return 0;
    }

    if (0 == dstSize)
    {
        return 0;
    }

    if (dstSize < srcSize * 2 + 1)
    {
        char tmp[256];
        size_t tmpLen = sizeof (tmp) > srcSize ? srcSize : sizeof (tmp);
        strlcpy (tmp, src, tmpLen);

        sys_err ("FATAL ERROR!! not enough buffer size (dstSize %u srcSize %u src%s: %s)", dstSize, srcSize, tmpLen != srcSize ? "(trimmed to 255 characters)" : "", tmp);

        dst[0] = '\0';
        return 0;
    }

    return mysql_real_escape_string (GetSQLHandle(), dst, src, srcSize);
}

void CAsyncSQL2::SetLocale (const std::string & stLocale)
{
    m_stLocale = stLocale;
    QueryLocaleSet();
}
```

This is my AsyncSQL.h

```
#ifndef __INC_METIN_II_ASYNCSQL_H__
#define __INC_METIN_II_ASYNCSQL_H__

#include "../../libthecore/src/stdafx.h"
#include "../../libthecore/src/log.h"
#include "../../Ayarlar.h"
#include <string>
#include <queue>
#include <vector>
#include <map>
#include <mysql/server/mysql.h>
#include <mysql/server/errmsg.h>
#include <mysql/server/mysqld_error.h>
#include "Semaphore.h"

typedef struct _SQLResult
{
    _SQLResult(): pSQLResult (NULL), uiNumRows (0), uiAffectedRows (0), uiInsertID (0) {}

    ~_SQLResult()
    {
        if (pSQLResult)
        {
            mysql_free_result (pSQLResult);
            pSQLResult = NULL;
        }
    }

    MYSQL_RES* pSQLResult;
    uint32_t uiNumRows;
    uint32_t uiAffectedRows;
    uint32_t uiInsertID;
} SQLResult;

typedef struct _SQLMsg
{
    _SQLMsg() : m_pkSQL (NULL), iID (0), uiResultPos (0), pvUserData (NULL), bReturn (false), uiSQLErrno (0) {}

    ~_SQLMsg()
    {
        auto first = vec_pkResult.begin();
        auto past  = vec_pkResult.end();

        while (first != past)
        {
            delete * (first++);
        }

        vec_pkResult.clear();
    }

    void Store()
    {
        do
        {
            SQLResult* pRes = new SQLResult;

            pRes->pSQLResult = mysql_store_result (m_pkSQL);
            pRes->uiInsertID = mysql_insert_id (m_pkSQL);
            pRes->uiAffectedRows = mysql_affected_rows (m_pkSQL);

            if (pRes->pSQLResult)
            {
                pRes->uiNumRows = mysql_num_rows (pRes->pSQLResult);
            }
            else
            {
                pRes->uiNumRows = 0;
            }

            vec_pkResult.push_back (pRes);
        }
        while (!mysql_next_result (m_pkSQL));
    }

    SQLResult* Get()
    {
        if (uiResultPos >= vec_pkResult.size())
        {
            return NULL;
        }

        return vec_pkResult[uiResultPos];
    }

    bool Next()
    {
        if (uiResultPos + 1 >= vec_pkResult.size())
        {
            return false;
        }

        ++uiResultPos;
        return true;
    }

    MYSQL* m_pkSQL;
    int iID;
    std::string stQuery;

    std::vector<SQLResult *> vec_pkResult;
    unsigned int uiResultPos;

    void* pvUserData;
    bool  bReturn;

    unsigned int uiSQLErrno;
} SQLMsg;

class CAsyncSQL
{
public:
    CAsyncSQL();
    virtual ~CAsyncSQL();

    void Quit();

    bool Setup (const char* c_pszHost, const char* c_pszUser, const char* c_pszPassword, const char* c_pszDB, const char* c_pszLocale, bool bNoThread = false, int iPort = 0);
    bool Setup (CAsyncSQL* sql, bool bNoThread = false);

    bool Connect();
    bool IsConnected()
    {
        return m_bConnected;
    }
    bool QueryLocaleSet();

    void AsyncQuery  (const char* c_pszQuery);
    void ReturnQuery (const char* c_pszQuery, void* pvUserData);
    SQLMsg* DirectQuery (const char* c_pszQuery);

    DWORD CountQuery();
    DWORD CountResult();

    void PushResult (SQLMsg* p);
    bool PopResult  (SQLMsg** pp);

    void ChildLoop();

    MYSQL* GetSQLHandle();

    int  CountQueryFinished();
    void ResetQueryFinished();

    size_t EscapeString (char* dst, size_t dstSize, const char* src, size_t srcSize);

protected:
    void Destroy();
    void PushQuery (SQLMsg* p);

    bool PeekQuery (SQLMsg** pp);
    bool PopQuery  (int iID);

    bool PeekQueryFromCopyQueue (SQLMsg** pp );
    INT  CopyQuery();
    bool PopQueryFromCopyQueue();

public:
    int  GetCopiedQueryCount();
    void ResetCopiedQueryCount();
    void AddCopiedQueryCount (int iCopiedQuery);

protected:
    MYSQL m_hDB;

    std::string m_stHost;
    std::string m_stUser;
    std::string m_stPassword;
    std::string m_stDB;
    std::string m_stLocale;

    int m_iMsgCount;
    int m_aiPipe[2];
    int m_iPort;

    std::queue<SQLMsg*> m_queue_query;
    std::queue<SQLMsg*> m_queue_query_copy;
    std::queue<SQLMsg*> m_queue_result;

    volatile bool m_bEnd;

    pthread_t m_hThread;
    pthread_mutex_t* m_mtxQuery;
    pthread_mutex_t* m_mtxResult;

    CSemaphore m_sem;

    int m_iQueryFinished;

    unsigned long m_ulThreadID;
    bool m_bConnected;
    int  m_iCopiedQuery;
};

class CAsyncSQL2 : public CAsyncSQL
{
public:
    void SetLocale (const std::string & stLocale);
};

#endif
```

And this is the function the reason of the error ;

optional:1052 ;

```
    #ifdef __cpp_lib_three_way_comparison
  template<typename _Tp>
    constexpr strong_ordering
    operator<=>(const optional<_Tp>& __x, nullopt_t) noexcept
    { return bool(__x) <=> false; }
#else
```

After a see a document the microsoft release i'm gonna try <= > false; like this and take a error again..

Best Regards.

Comment: Can you make a [mre] so that we can see code that actually triggers this compilation error?

Comment: I'm edited the question and add the needed files to look, thnks.

Comment: Better but now you  instead have alot of irrelevant code and it's still not possible for us to reproduce the error. Try to narrow it down into a _minimal_ program that doesn't require any of your header files, like `"../../Ayarlar.h"`. The error seems to be related to a `map`, but I don't see where a `map` is used in your code.

Comment: Ayarlar.h is the basic settings header, include some defines nothing else.Every line the compiler gives me is the point map file, i dont understand either.I wonder what kind a code block trigger this three way comparison, i dont know what i need to search in my files.Sorry for my poor eng and thanks for the help, best regards.

Comment: Ok, then I suggest doing it like this: Copy your project into a new project. Start removing stuff that you don't think have anything to do with the error (like the mentioned header files). When removing stuff, compile the project, remove, compile, remove ... until suddenly - it will compile. The last thing you removed was the culprit.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I ve no idea why it looks is getting bool(__x) <=> false as an bool and int comparison.
I would think you got some strange macro in your files included before to include the  header that is going to break the standard code.
I would suggest you try to move above the standard headers and below them your 'user defined' headers.

```
#include <string>
#include <queue>
#include <vector>
#include <map>
#include <mysql/server/mysql.h>
#include <mysql/server/errmsg.h>
#include <mysql/server/mysqld_error.h>
#include "../../libthecore/src/stdafx.h"
#include "../../libthecore/src/log.h"
#include "../../Ayarlar.h"
#include "Semaphore.h"
```

EDIT:
i ve found the cause of the problem.
a macro defined in "libthrecore/stdafx.h" (i own the files that is using the author, they are public).

```
#ifndef false
#define false   0
#define true    (!false)
#endif
```

it is causing false to be read as a int and is causing the spaceship operator to fails with the error shown by the author. Move up the standard headers or remove the macro to solve the error.